# x and y values are not stored after the code cycles once

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about designing this code in a way that, when I make it loop, the (x,y) values from the previous cycles will be stored in the program. Right now, if I add a loop block to the program, the (x,y) values reset with each input.

```
question = (input("Where do you want to go?: "));
y = 0
x = 0
if question in ["up"]:
    y = y + 1
    print("You've moved up one unit!")
    print("Your position is now ", x, y)

if question in ["down"]:
    y = y - 1
    print("You've moved down one unit!")
    print("Your position is now ", x, y)

if question in ["right"]:
    x = x + 1
    print("You've moved right one unit!")
    print("Your position is now ", x, y)

if question in ["left"]:
    y = y + 1
    print("You've moved left one unit!")
    print("Your position is now ", x, y)    

else:
    print("You can't go there.")
```

Comment: Show how you've added the loop that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a loop and x,y reset with each input, it sounds like you need to move x,y out of the loop:

```
x=0
y=0
while True:
    # ask the question
    # process
```

Instead of:

```
while True:
    # ask the question
    x=0
    y=0
    # process
```

Comment: Is there some variation of the "while true" statement that will cause the loop to end conditionally, as opposed to the code being infinitely looped?

Comment: Put a condition in the `while` loop, or within the loop do something like `if question == 'quit': break`.  The `break` keyword will exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize x and y outside the loop

```
y = 0
x = 0
while True:
   question = (input("Where do you want to go?: "))
   ...
```

otherwise those lines are executed every time execution gets to the top of the loop